# passing data from one window to other window in javascript

Tags: javascript, gsp

Is there any JQuery event which would set the text box value in another screen which is opened in another tab.

e.g.  If my new connection and view connection screen are opened in two IE windows, I changed circuit which is set in object reminder in one window.
It should change the circuit name which is set in all window also.

It is not on a button click.
It should fire after an ajax call.

e.g:

```
 success : function(data) {
      $('#cirIdInMainGSP').val(selectedCirId);    
     }
```

But, it is changing the value in current window where I am, not in other window.
How can I set the values in other window without refreshing it?

My scenario is I have a global textbox which is displayed in all the pages.
In any of the page I can change the text box value. Just after changing the value the same should be displayed in all the windows wothout refershing.
As of now,I have to refresh my other pages to see the changed value.
Refresh by F5.

If any idea you have it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML5 localStorage to save data in browser.
Save it on every key press of that textbox.
Try to read it by using a timer on the other page.

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: I am really sorry Issac. COuld not get hold of the concept after reading the web url.Distance dream it is to implement.I am using GRAILS.Does it support HTML5 storage.If it does, would you mind some way to implement this please?

Comment: Hello Debasis Mohapatra, HTML5 storage depends upon the browser. It doesn't matter which server side language you use. In the clientside it will be always javascript.

localStorage.setItem("key", value);
var value  = localStorage.getItem("key");

Comment: Thanks Issac.Got that.But in order to show the latest value selected in one window, I have to refresh it manually by F5 to reflect the change in other window.It cant do automatically.Same text box is there for whole application.This should be displayed all the time.If the user changes the textbox value in one tab,where or not I navigate to other tabs,it should change the value in all the opened tabs.It can do refresh or anything.That thing it cant do.Tries with localstorage.Not able to do it.

Comment: using setInterval you can update the textbox without refreshing the page.

Comment: This my textbox with id  objRemTxtBoxId.  Is this code right                      var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#objRemTxtBoxId').load('samp.jsp').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000);   How can I exclude the jsp url option?I just want to refresh the textbox with id. Can you pliz give the syntax?  Thankss

Comment: setInterval(function(){
 var value = localStorage.getItem('key');
 $('#objRemTxtBoxId').val(value);
},1000);

Comment: Nice to hear that.. Welcome :-)